# Python Requests with Dropdown

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new to parsing and I have a problem scrape information from this webpage: https://www.channelcrawler.com

I am trying to use the POST request method to fill in all the fields and execute a channel search request, but every time the server returns 500 (Internal Server Error) and I don't understand why this is

```py
import requests

payload = {'queryName': 'xyz',
           'multicategory': '2',
           'multitopic':'1',
           'multilanguage':'382',
           'multicountry': '2',
           'queryMinPublishedOn': '7',
           'queryMaxPublishedOn' : '14',
           'queryMinSubs': '0',
           'queryMaxSubs': '100',
           'queryMinViews': '0',
           'queryMaxViews': '10000',
           'queryMinVideos': '0',
           'queryMaxVideos': '10',
           'queryMinLastVideoDate': '7',
           'queryMaxLastVideoDate': '14',
           'queryDescription': ''
}

r = requests.post('https://www.channelcrawler.com/eng', data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Sometimes the request is processed, but without taking into account the entered values, that is, the site displays all possible channels.
I think that there may be a problem with the "Search" button, because when you try to add it to `payload` as follows `{'submit': 'Search'}`, the code does not display anything.
I am at a dead end with this problem, and I can not figure it out for a full hour.

Comment: You are supplying the id's of the input fields.  A `<form>` submittal uses the `name` attribute of the input fields.  Have you done a request by hand with the browser developer tools to see what it sends?

Comment: I didn’t make a request manually using developer tools due to lack of knowledge in this area. What if they have the same ```name``` attribute?

Comment: I don't think that will be a problem.  The actual field names are like `data[query][min_views]` and `data[query][max_views}`, and the dropdowns become `query[language_id][]` and `query[topic_id][]`.  You NEED to look at the actual POST info the site creates if you hope to hack into this.